# Convert integer to unsigned byte array with java or android

Tags: java, c#, android, arrays, bitconverter

Hi i have seen many links in SO to convert integer value to unsigned byte array. but i can't able to get clear idea. my conversion is as follows

//in android

```
int checksum=104396;

byte[] byteArray = GetBytesInt(checksum);

public static byte[] GetBytesInt(int value) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        bytes[0] = (byte) (value >> 24);
        bytes[1] = (byte) (value >> 16);
        bytes[2] = (byte) (value >> 8);
        bytes[3] = (byte) (value);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Output in android
[0,1,-105,-52]

//in c#

```
uint CheckSum=104396;

byte[] byteArray=BitConverter.GetBytes(CheckSum)

where BitConverter is System method
```

output in c#

[204,151,1,0]

How i get this output in java or android. I check java 8 and Guava there are returning the same.

please help me with some coding

Comment: `Output in android`. You did not post the code that outputs.

Comment: i mentioned the op byte value below the code

Comment: No. I saw the output already of course. But i asked for the code you used to produce the output. How did you print them?

Comment: You see that the result is ok? Java and C# produce equal results. Add 256 to negative values in Android. Only the sequence is different. You should consider each byte value as unsigned when printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @greenapps suggestion, Getting byte array in LITTLE_ENDIAN format solved the problem.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
byteBuffer.putInt((int) (value & 0xffffffffL));
byte[] array=Bytes.asList(byteBuffer.array())
```

Output in android

[-52,-105,1,0]